# Optimizing my godot game's size (Mono version)

Tags: c#, linux, scons, godot

Does anyone here know how I can optimize my game's export size in godot 3.3 mono version?

I tried building godot mono from source as mentioned in the docs:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/compiling/compiling_with_mono.html
it works fine but when I add the optimization commands as mentioned in the docs (but for mono version):
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/compiling/optimizing_for_size.html
I ran into a problem when I used this command:

```
    scons platform=x11 target=release_debug tools=yes optimize=speed mono_glue=no mono_prefix=/opt/mono/ module_gridmap_enabled=no module_hdr_enabled=no module_jpg_enabled=no module_jsonrpc_enabled=no module_mobile_vr_enabled=no module_mono_enabled=yes module_ogg_enabled=no module_opensimplex_enabled=no module_opus_enabled=no module_regex_enabled=yes module_stb_vorbis_enabled=no module_tga_enabled=no module_theora_enabled=no module_tinyexr_enabled=no module_upnp_enabled=no module_visual_script_enabled=no module_vorbis_enabled=no module_webm_enabled=no module_webp_enabled=no no_editor_splash=yes -j3
```

it compiled well but when it's finished, I needed to generate the glue using:

```
    bin/godot.x11.opt.tools.64.mono --generate-mono-glue modules/mono/glue
```

I get this error: **symbol lookup error: /lib64/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZTIPi**
but when I build with this command only:

```
scons platform=x11 target=release_debug tools=yes mono_glue=no mono_prefix=/opt/mono/
```

Everything works just fine, but I don't need to build the engine from source if I am not getting any size optimization.

Any body Can help me with this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be unique to you: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20923, which has no answers at the moment but one suspects an incompatible Mono version.